# Nginx non existing domains can not be routed to 404 page

Tags: nginx

My Nginx config file is included several server blocks that it's shown as below. With the following configuration, it redirects non-existing domains to the first server block in the config file. However I would like to redirect non-existing domains to 404 page.

```
 server 
{    
listen      443 ssl http2;
server_name     test-domain.no;
access_log  /var/log/nginx/nginx.access.log;
error_log   /var/log/nginx/nginx.error.log;
ssl    on;
ssl_certificate    /etc/nginx/ssl/certificates.pem;
ssl_certificate_key    /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256';
ssl_session_timeout 1d;
ssl_session_cache builtin:1000 shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_tickets off;

location /
{
    proxy_pass         http://test-domain-sps.3fcf2715.cont.dockerapp.io:80/;
    proxy_redirect     off;

    ##proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    client_max_body_size       10m;
    client_body_buffer_size    128k;

    proxy_connect_timeout      90;
    proxy_send_timeout         90;
    proxy_read_timeout         90;

    proxy_buffer_size          4k;
    proxy_buffers              4 32k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
}
}

# Redirect from HTTP to HTTPS
server { 
 listen 80;
 server_name test-domain.no; 
 return 301 https://test-domain.no$request_uri;
 #rewrite ^/(.*) https://test-domain.no/$1 permanent; 
}

#others server blocks...
```

I appreciate if you let me know how I can routes non-existing domain in the config file to 404 page.

Edited:

Default nginx.conf:

```
 # cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf                                                                                                                                              


user  nginx;                                                                                                                                                             

worker_processes  1;                                                                                                                                                     

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;                                                                                                                                

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;                                                                                                                                           


events {                                                                                                                                                                 
  worker_connections  1024;                                                                                                                                            

}                                                                                                                                                                        


http {                                                                                                                                                                   
 include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;                                                                                                                                 
 default_type  application/octet-stream;                                                                                                                              

 log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '                                                                                            
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '                                                                                                        
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';                                                                                                      

 access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;                                                                                                                         

 sendfile        on;                                                                                                                                                  
 #tcp_nopush     on;                                                                                                                                                  

 keepalive_timeout  65;                                                                                                                                               

 #gzip  on;                                                                                                                                                           

 include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;                                                                                                                                    

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the following configuration to return 404 header.

```
server {
  server_name _;
  listen 80 default_server;
  return 404;
}
```

If you need to add a custom 404 page then you can use the following

```
server {
  server_name _;
  listen 80 default_server;
  error_page 404 http://example.com/404.html;
  return 404;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would it also work for the non-existing domain in https?

Comment: It will not work for https because you will not have a valid certificate for it.

Comment: I tested for a non-existing domain in my nginx file like: client-test.domain.no but it still routes to the first server block: https://test-domain.no. Any idea?

Comment: Do you have another block that has default_server or server_name _; Can you check the default nginx.conf file?

Comment: No, I've put the default nginx.conf in the question.

Comment: If you configure a corresponding `default_server` block with `listen 443 ssl` and corresponding certificate files, then you will get a certificate conflict because the certificate doesn't match the domain name.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen OK, I see. But I set listen 80 default_server, however it still routes to the first block. I would appreciate if you can help me with this issue.

Comment: You need to create a `server` block with `listen 443 ssl default_server`.

Comment: Try to remove lines after 

`#others server blocks...`

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Thank you Tero and spilia. I needed to delete my cache to see the result after changes.

Answer (score 0):

I've set up the following lines in the end of config file for non-existing HTTPS domains and it works fine. As it might be helpful for someone, I post it here:

```
server {
 server_name _;
 listen 443 ssl;
 ssl_certificate    /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.pem;
 ssl_certificate_key    /etc/nginx/ssl/serve.key;
 return 404;
}
```